# Slide out description after clicking image in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make animation when opening image kinda like is here: http://arzbhatia.com/ in portfolio section.

This is what I've already done, but it's not working properly.

Here is jFiddle of what I've done: [jFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYXcf/)

The div is showing in the same place, no matter which image I click. If I remove position:absoulte from #test_div it seem to add div after image, moving rest of them to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did change your fiddle, and created rows. Try it like this:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYXcf/4/

Comment: Ok, that works great, but when i open upper image description and then try to open the bottom one nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The div is in the same place because the images are being floated out of their parent (the LI).  This is visible in the Chrome Dev Tools if you hover over the list elements.

The fix is to not float anything and to make the LIs `display:inline-block` so that they occupy space in the dom.  You also need to add some Javascript to increase the height of the LI to accommodate `#test_div` when it gets added because it's positioning is absolute.

Full code here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYXcf/3/

**Updated code here**: http://fiddle.jshell.net/MYXcf/5/

Comment: It works pretty nice, but there is a problem with sliding images. I want for the description to slide out below first line of images, while moving second line below that description. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put another div named description into all you li.
Like this :

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li class="image_item">
            <img class="gal_images" src="http://goo.gl/rpys4M">
            <div class="description"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="image_item">
            <img class="gal_images" src="http://goo.gl/rpys4M">
            <div class="description"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="image_item">
            <img class="gal_images" src="http://goo.gl/rpys4M">
            <div class="description"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="image_item">
            <img class="gal_images" src="http://goo.gl/rpys4M">
            <div class="description"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And some css to style this up :

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#gallery {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.click_images {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.gal_images {
    height: 220px;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
}
.image_item {
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
}
#test_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.description {
    display: none;
}
```

And the jQuery, will toggle if the description is already opened or not, if its opened, it'll hide, else it'll open.

```
var opened = false;
$('.image_item').click(function () {
    if (!opened) {
        opened = true;
        $(this).find('.description').slideDown('500').append('hahaha');
    } else {
        opened = false;
        $(this).find('.description').slideUp('500');
    }

});
```

You'll find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fm9L4/

Comment: Your jfiddle doesn't seem to work.. And it doesn't seem to be working correctly..

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like the description to be full width of the site. Your solution seems to work only with the width of the image. And is kinda lagging it seems.